# How to initiate Chrome Canary in headless mode through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless, chrome-canary

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = 'C:\Users\mpmccurdy\Desktop\Google Chrome Canary.lnk'
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
```

Comment: when i run this script, chrome browser stills pulls up

Comment: What are the chrome and the chrome driver versions that you are using? Try with `options.add_argument('--headless')` if your chrome version > 59

Comment: i have version 67.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using *Chrome Canary* as a basic [Requirement](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#requirements) the server still expects you to have *Chrome* installed in the default location as per the underlying OS architecture as follows:

[image: Chrome_binary_expected_location]

You can also override the default *Chrome Binary Location* following the documentation [Using a Chrome executable in a non-standard location](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities#TOC-Using-a-Chrome-executable-in-a-non-standard-location) as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
path = os.getcwd() +'\\chromedriver.exe' #needs to be in your current working directory
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=path)
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: also, i am on windows