# Why XPath does not highlighted the yellow mark in Chrome84?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, xpath, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

Why XPath does not highlight the yellow mark? I try to find the XPath at [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

> `//*[@id="fakebox-input"]`

It is found but not highlighted being the yellow mark on Chrome so it's hard for me to found out exactly where is the XPath and to see the XPath correct or not.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Comment: You've still not created a [mcve].  Your question should stand on its own, not be dependent upon a link that can change in the future or change depending on the viewer.  (For example, that XPath returns an empty array for me at that site at this moment in time and with my current set of extensions.  Evaluating this expression, `$x('//@id').map(x => x.value)`,  in the console returns a list of 43 id values, none of which are `fakebox-input`.)  Post a self-contained example in your question if you want further help.

Comment: recent update of Chrome 84 is buggy you can find more details on https://stackoverflow.com/a/62972580/5400362.

Answer (score 4):

Here the major issue is with [DevTools within Google Chrome 84.0](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/devtools) which doesn't highlights the first matched element.

Incase, the locator finds a single match, the search result does show **`1 of 1`** but the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) is not highlighted within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes)

As an example, the *Search Box* within the [*Google Home Page*](https://www.google.com/) can be identified uniquely using the [css-selector](/questions/tagged/css-selector):

```
[name='q']
```

or using the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
//*[@name='q']
```

But [google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) within Google Chrome 84.0, does finds the element and shows `1 of 1` but the element is not highlighted.

[image: devtools_issue]

However, if there are multiple element matching to the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890), leaving out the first matched element, the other elements are highlighted.

---

### Bug in Chrome v84.0.4147.89

This issue was raised in the `Platform>DevTools` queue through [Issue 1108311: The first matched element in the Elements panel is not getting highlighted as per the cssSelector](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1108311) and had been merged into [Issue 1103316: Elements search does not resolveNode (highlight text, etc) on first search result](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1103316) where we are actively tracking the issue.

---

### Solution

As per `@bugdroid` the main issue was caused because a check to ensure the search results were valid did not account for the case where the index was `0`, so all highlight results of index `0` (index `1` to the user) were no longer highlighted.

The [fix](https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/dc805d4963d449fce0b748bacf3422bfb3413d81) for this issue is **Merge-Approved**  in:

- *Chrome* version [**84.0**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1103316#c15) later then **Version 84.0.4147.89**.
- *Chrome* version [**85.0**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1103316#c17).
- [Chrome Canary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606929/how-to-initiate-chrome-canary-in-headless-mode-through-selenium-and-python/50608556#50608556) version [**86.0.4201.0**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1103316#c4).

---

### Alternate Strategies

You have two(2) other approaches as solutions as follows:

- In the first approach, as per the article [Fix site issues with the new Issues tab](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/devtools#issues) you can use the command **`document.querySelector()`** through the newly added `Console` tab within the second Drawer from the top to query the element through the *css-selector* as follows:

[image: query_selector_css]

- In the other approach, you can click on the `Console` tab, next to `Element` tab and execute the either of the following xpath/css commands:

  - [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) command as:

    ```
    $x("//*[@name='q']")
    ```
  - Snapshot of identification:

[image: console_tab_xpath]

- [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) command as:

  ```
  $$("[name='q']")
  ```
- Snapshot of identification:

[image: console_tab_css-selector]

Answer (score 2):

The bounty belongs to @DebanjanB however to add a quick note that they've now fixed this in at least Version 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Just go to [chrome://settings/help](http://chrome://settings/help)  an let chrome update.

This is this page, working for a single highlight
[image: devtools working]

Comment: It's a minor push and doesn't needs user intervention. So explicitly browsing to chrome://settings/help may not be required as the minor pushes are automatic.