# How to locate an element inside this iframe with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I am tring to access an element inside this iframe:

[image: I am tring to access an element inside this iframe]

I tried to use `switch_to.frame(0)` first, but still can not locate the element inside the frame.

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='To Do Assignments in Connect'][src='https://connect.mheducation.com/paamweb/index.html#/access/home']")))
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='To Do Assignments in Connect' and @src='https://connect.mheducation.com/paamweb/index.html#/access/home']")))
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How can I select a html element no matter what frame it is in in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47771879/7429447)

Comment: It is still not able to locate the element inside.

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="iframewrapper"]/iframe')))
driver.find_element(By.ID,'menu-text')

Comment: `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="iframewrapper"]/iframe'))) driver.find_element(By.ID,'menu-text')` isn't what I have suggested either.

Comment: Sounds to be a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.

Comment: The problem is solved. Would you mind telling me why are the XPath and CSS selector you gave me different from the ones I copied from the web page and how did you come up with them?

Comment: @elephish Unfortunately I still don't know which _xpath_ or _css_ you have used.

Comment: I just right-clicked that line of code and selected "Copy XPath". It gave me "//*[@id="iframewrapper"]/iframe" for the XPath and "/html/body/app-root/page-connect/div[3]/container-iframe/section/div/iframe" for the full xpath.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46702281/7429447) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63073849/7429447) discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to the frame:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
```