# WebDriverException: Unknown Error - First element in result.deepSerializedValue.value list must contain a string

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception, microsoft-edge, ui-automation

**Description:**

I am facing an issue while using Selenium with Java, Cucumber, and EdgeDriver (Microsoft Edge version 120.0.2210.61). The error occurs when attempting to interact with an element inside an iframe. The stack trace indicates a WebDriverException with the message "unknown error: first element in result.deepSerializedValue.value list must contain a string."

**Environment Information:**

Selenium Version: 4.3.0
Java Version: 11.0.1
Operating System: Windows 10
EdgeDriver Version: 120.0.2210.61

**Error Details:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: first element in result.deepSerializedValue.value list must contain a string
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=120.0.2210.61)
Build info: version: '4.3.0', revision: 'a4995e2c09*'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: 'xxx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
Command: [579019f1b79294be0bb09d7702a08696, findElement {using=xpath, value=//*[@id='tool.edit.saveContainer_arrow']}]
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
// Code snippet where the error occurs
driver.switchTo().frame(0); // Switching to iframe
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tool.edit.saveContainer_arrow']"));
element.click(); // Error occurs here
```

[image]

**Additional Context:**

The issue specifically happens within an iframe (iframe index 0).
The exception points to a problem with the element's deepSerializedValue.value list.
Request for Assistance:
I would appreciate any insights or solutions on how to address this WebDriverException in EdgeDriver while interacting with elements inside an iframe. If there are workarounds or specific configurations needed, please share your expertise.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

**UPDATE:**
We've identified a key aspect related to the mentioned issue. The element we intend to interact with is located within the 'contentframe.' However, the 'contentframe' itself contains a child frame named 'updateFlowchartFrame,' which Selenium code is currently unable to detect. Although it appears to be a nested frame, Selenium is unable to switch to this 'updateFlowchartFrame' and execute any actions. I've included the DOM below for reference. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: The issue might be related with handling iframe elements incorrectly. You can refer to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71729540/how-to-locate-an-element-inside-this-iframe-with-selenium about how to locate an element in iframe with selenium.

Comment: It seems the issue doesn't lie with handling iframe elements incorrectly, as I am able to successfully switch to the iframe. However, after the switch, when attempting to click on an element within the frame, the error mentioned above is thrown

Comment: Could you please provide the website link you're trying to automate so that we can have a test on our side?

Comment: Thank you for your understanding. Unfortunately, I am unable to share the specific details of the banking application as it involves sensitive information, and access requires admin credentials. However, I can provide you with any necessary code snippets, descriptions, or logs related to the automation process. If there are specific aspects or functionalities you would like me to elaborate on or provide details about, please let me know, and I'll do my best to share those without compromising security protocols.

Comment: It's difficult to investigate further without the website code structure. You can try to check if you locate the element correctly. Besides, your Selenium version is a little bit old, you can try to update.

Comment: Here were some of our findings!

Objective: The objective is to access iframe B.

Upon inspecting the webpage, it was identified that iframe B is nested under iframe A on the same page.

Method 1:

Switch to defaultContent -> iframe A -> iframe B
Results: Encounter unknown error - 'first element in result.deepSerializedValue.value list must contain a string.'
Method 2:

Switch to defaultContent -> iframe B
Results: Unable to locate the element.

Comment: To access a nested iframe, we need first switch to the outermost iframe, then switch to the inner iframe, before getting the targeted web element. You can try code like below: `driver.switchTo().frame(“contentframe”); driver.switchTo().frame(“updateFlowchartFrame”); WebElement frame2element = driver.FindElement(By.xpath("xxx"));`

Comment: Implemented the aforementioned approach, but encountered an unknown error. This issue arises because Selenium is unable to detect any existing iframes nested within the 'contentframe'.