# Chrome Elements console does not show unique element when given xPath

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom, xpath, console

if I press `F12`, go to `Elements` and click `ctrl+F` to search for a xPath, if I find only one element, that element is not highlighted (but Chrome will point out `1 of 1`). If i find more than one elements, Chrome highlights from the second one. Problem occures also when I use indexes in xPath: `(//a)[1]`.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are talking about this bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1106703 which was reported in the Chromium issue forums.

It was introduced in Chrome 84 with this change https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/devtools

I guess we can only wait or downgrade to Chrome 83 (which might not be possible in a corporate environment)

Comment: ah, bloody hell.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Chrome returns every element with an attribute containing part of an url (`meta` with `@content`, `script` with `@src`,...). That's why you got a `script` element when `//a` is your input. However, `(//a)[1]` should work and should return the first anchor (tested fine with `Edge Chromium` and `Chrome`).

Try to use this workaround to select the element :

```
//a[self::a]
```

To get the first anchor on the page, use :

```
(//a[self::a])[1]
```

Images for reference :

[image: A]
[image: B]
[image: C]

Comment: It did not work. It's doing the same thing, it finds the element but it does not highlight it

Comment: Checking better, it does not show some other //a elements, don't know why, it seems random.

Comment: OK. As suggested by @Oikuar, downgrade your Chrome version or use the built-in JS console (`$x('//a')`) or `ChroPath` addon to test your XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is [DevTools within Google Chrome 84.0](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/05/devtools) doesn't highlights the first matching element.

If, the locator finds a single match, the search result does show `1 of 1` but the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) isn't getting highlighted within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

As a demonstration, the *Search Box* within the [*Google Home Page*](https://www.google.com/) can be identified uniquely using the [css-selector](/questions/tagged/css-selector):

```
[name='q']
```

or using the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
//*[@name='q']
```

[google-chrome-devtools](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-devtools) within Google Chrome 84.0, does finds the element and shows `1 of 1` but the element is not getting highlighted.

[image: devtools_issue]

Incase, there are multiple element matching to the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890), barring the first matched element, the other elements does gets highlighted.

---

### Bug in Chrome 84

This issue was raised within `Platform>DevTools` queue through [Issue 1108311: The first matched element in the Elements panel is not getting highlighted as per the cssSelector](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1108311) and had been merged into [Issue 1103316: Elements search does not resolveNode (highlight text, etc) on first search result](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1103316) where we are actively tracking the issue.

---

### Solution

As per `@bugdroid` the main issue was caused because a check to ensure the search results were valid did not account for the case where the index was `0`, so all highlight results of index `0` (index `1` to the user) were no longer highlighted.

The [fix](https://chromium.googlesource.com/devtools/devtools-frontend/+/dc805d4963d449fce0b748bacf3422bfb3413d81) for this issue is **Merge-Approved**  in:

- *Chrome* version [84.0](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1103316#c15) later then **Version 84.0.4147.89**.
- *Chrome* version [85.0](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1103316#c17).
- [Chrome Canary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606929/how-to-initiate-chrome-canary-in-headless-mode-through-selenium-and-python/50608556#50608556) version [86.0.4201.0](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1103316#c4).

---

### Alternate Solution

For alternate solutions using the current [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) **Version 84.0.4147.89** you can find a detailed discussion in [Why XPath does not highlighted the yellow mark in Chrome84?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62945647/why-xpath-does-not-highlighted-the-yellow-mark-in-chrome84/63073849#63073849)