# chromedriver v85 seems to break current_url method

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

In updating from chromedriver 84 to 85, the current_url method is not returning the correct current url.  It appears v85 only returns the end of the url.

Answer (score 1):

From the [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) page:

- *Current stable release: [ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=84.0.4147.30/)*
- *Current beta release: [ChromeDriver 85.0.4183.38](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=85.0.4183.38/)*

---

### Current stable release

The **current stable release** is well tested and have passed the *alpha* and *beta* test before the public release and can be safely used in the *Production Environment*.

---

### Current beta release

The **current beta release** is still under *beta* test and is exclusively for [**Chrome Canary**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606929/how-to-initiate-chrome-canary-in-headless-mode-through-selenium-and-python/50608556#50608556), the *Nightly build for developers* and in any case shouldn't be used in the *Production Environment*.

Answer (score 0):

My work-around for now is to simply do this:

retURL=driver.execute_script("return document.location.href;")